# Wordpress have_comments does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set a comment() condition in wordpress. This condition is set in comments.php just as the wordpress default theme does.

Then the whole comments.php file is loaded using comment_template; Now, when I remove have_comments() condition, everything works and all the comments are loaded, but when I add this condition, it returns false as if there are no comments.

Here is my whole comments.php file:

```
<?php
/**
| This page deals with the comment-system and template in the Behdis Marketing Group Wordpress Theme.   
**/
$commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
$req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
$aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );
$fields =  array(
    'author' => "<div><input type='text' name='author' placeholder='Full Name' /></div>",
    'email'  => "<div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email /></div>", 
);

$comments_args = array(
    'fields' =>  $fields,
    'comment_field' => "<div class=\"comment-component\"><textarea name=\"comment\" id=\"comment\" ></textarea></div>",
    'comment_notes_after' => '',
    'title_reply' => 'Write your comment...',
    'title_reply_to' => 'Reply',
    'label_submit' => 'Comment!',
    'comment_notes_before' => "<p class='simple-title'>" . 'Your email is kept secret forever' . ' '
);

comment_form($comments_args);
?>
<?php

    if( have_comments() )
    {       
?>
<section class='post-comments'>

    <?php
        $comments = get_comments();
        foreach($comments as $comm)
        {
            ?>
            <div class='post-each-comment'>
            <p class="post-each-comment-meta">
            <?php echo $comm->comment_author;?> در تاریخ <?php comment_time();?>
            </p>
            <?php echo $comm->comment_content;   ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
</section>
    <?php
    }// end of have_comments()
   else
    {
        ?>
        <div class='no-comment' >
            No comments, be the first visitor to comment on this post!
        </div>
        <?php   
    }
    ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `get_comments_number` is what many devs are looking for... WordPress often does a horrible job naming their functions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43816450/1718491

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call [`have_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_comments) before you call [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

It's likely just the issue you have the wrong processing-flow here. Wordpress makes use of global static state so the order of things is important (and easy to miss):

```
<?php

    $comments = get_comments();

    if( have_comments() )
    {       
?>
<section class='post-comments'>

    <?php        
        foreach($comments as $comm)
        {
            ?>
            <div class='post-each-comment'>
```

Also codex says that `have_comments()` depends on the loop so that is `$post`. It could be that even my example code suggestion above does not make it to deal with the static state properly so you need to trouble-shoot this is a little to find out what to use.

E.g. as `get_comments()` returns an array this normally does it:

```
<?php

    $comments = get_comments();

    if( $comments )
    {       
?>
<section class='post-comments'>

    <?php        
        foreach($comments as $comm)
        {
            ?>
            <div class='post-each-comment'>
```

As you can see a call to `have_comments()` is not necessary.

Hope this helps and take care.

Comment: Sorry you mean I have to put have_comments() after get_comments() ? I already have tested this prior to the above code, none of them works.

Comment: @Mostafa: As written that might not do it, see the second example it doesn't use `has_comments()` at all. AFAIK `has_comments()` is for the-loop-pages not for the comments page.

Comment: Somebody helps me please! I got stopped by this issue

Comment: @Mostafa: Well if the second example doesn't do it for you then you have a different problem as you ask for. It's just that *there are no comments*.

Answer (score 4):

This problem occurs when you query for comments before setting up the comments. You can use `comments_template(..)` to load the page containing `have_comments()` to set up the comments properly.

Comment: This was the right answer in my case. I tried to do a simple `get_template_part()`, which didn't load the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some hours for it. Might be it will be helpful for somebody.

When I tried to use `get_template_part('comments');` in my template for   using comments.php on page - it didn't work and `have_comments();` returned me `bool(false)`

Thanks for this post. I've used `comments_template();` instead get_template_part. And it works. I think that main cause is Wordpress makes use of global static state, and you need to use comments_template() with single post or page to save it.