# Wordpress - Why does have_comments() not work?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been tackling this problem for the last few hours and cannot find out why nor find any help anywhere online.

So pretty much, I'm making a custom theme from scratch. WordPress always starts off with a default "Hello world!" post and a default comment associated with that post.

The "Hello world!" post should not evaluate to false but for some reason it does.
 As you can see, I've tried using the comments_templates function WordPress offers to allow running code from a file named "comments.php" but that just added a factor of error to my problem and doing that, the code in "comments.php" is never even accessed, so for now, I'm leaving it out.

---

**What is shown when the code below is executed**  
[image]

---

**Proof there is a comment that should be shown** 
[image]

---

```
<?php
  if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
    // comments_template('/comments.php', true);
    if(have_comments()) :
      echo 'OMG COMMENTS WORK';
      foreach (get_comments() as $comment) :
        echo $comment -> comment_content;
        echo $comment -> comment_author;
        echo apply_filters('comment_text', $comment -> comment_content);
      endforeach;
    else :
      echo 'There are no comments to display here (this statement may or may not be true...)';
    endif;
  endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_comments):
Warning: this function will always return "false" until after comments_template has been called. If you need to check for comments before calling comments_template, use get_comments_number instead.