# Wordpress > Yoast > How to adjust (or disable) Meta-Robots for Comment-URLs?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags, yoast

It would be wonderful if someone could enlighten me about the use of meta-robots for comment-urls in Yoast.

As you can see in the source code of these example URL:

https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/geschwindigkeitsueberschreitung/comment-page-2/
https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/geschwindigkeitsueberschreitung/comment-page-3/

two contradicting meta-robots commands are played out. The first one says “noindex”, whereas the second one from Yoast says “index”. There should be one unique meta-robots tag for these comment URLs saying “noindex, follow”.

How can I possibly make Yoast either turn its “index, follow” meta-robots tag into a “noindex, follow” one or, even better, completely disable Yoast meta-robots only on comment URLs?

Surfing on the web I found a code-snippet that could help me with the latter:

```
add_filter( ‘wpseo_robots’, ‘yoast_seo_robots_remove_single’ );

function yoast_seo_robots_remove_single( $robots ) {
if ( is_single ( 123456 ) ) {
return false;
} else {
return $robots;}
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to change “is_single ( 123456 )” into a different identifier, which includes all the comment URLs, and nothing else.

Looking forward for any valuable hints!

Stay positive & test negative,
Roman

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much to go on here.

We can retrieve the [`paginate_comments_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_comments_links/) and access the `current` key, which should return the current comment page number. I'm not using [`is_paged()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_paged/) because I'm not able to verify if a comment page is considered as a nth page (eg: If it has the `<!--nextpage-->` quickTag).

We can use [`get_comments_number()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number/) to retrieve the current comment count. I'm not using [`have_comments`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_comments/) as we would be calling it outside the comment loop (@see [Wordpress have_comments does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932807/3645650)).

```php
<?php

add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', function () {

    if ( is_single() ) {

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
    
        $current_page = paginate_comments_links()['current'];
    
        if ( comments_open( $post_id ) && get_comments_number( get_the_ID() ) > 0 && $current_comment_page > 1 ) {

            return false;
    
        };

    };

};
```

`wpseo_robots` is the hook used by Yoast to output the meta tag.

Comment: In case you did not get the notification from @amarinediary from my answer, please look above/below :)

Comment: I already mentioned a similar method in the body of my question. In case I would add add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', '__return_false' ); to the theme´s function.php, it will affect ALL the pages, which will screw up the whole site. How can I let add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', '__return_false' ) fire only on the paginated comments page?

Comment: These pages are generated through Settings -> Discussion -> Other comment settings -> Break comments into pages with XXXX top level comments per page and the first/last page displayed by default.

They are no custom post types, but, so to speak, WP-pages, generated via the standard WP-functionality (no plugins, no 3rd party or custom code).

Comment: I added your code snippet to the functions.php, deleted the cache via wp-rocket, opened https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/geschwindigkeitsueberschreitung/comment-page-2/ in chrome incognito, and <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1" /> is still there :/ ... any idea of why it is not working?

Comment: When I add just  add_filter( 'wpseo_robots', '__return_false' );   to functions.php, meta-robots are removed from all the pages as expected.

Comment: I've edited my initial answer (as it had a bit of nonsense). I'm not using Yoast so this is untested.

Answer (score 0):

#### I had a custom noindex logic function and ended up combining it with Yoast's filter.

- What I had already was a noindex logic function `is_noindexfollow`, allowing me **conditional control over URLs based on regex, query params**, and `is_single`, `is_page`
- I combined it with yoast filter instead of attaching it to the head myself.
- Since I could not find a way to remove yoast's meta robots tag, it made more sense to weave my solution into it.

It demonstrates how OP could use Regex Pattern matching for cases that fall outside is_single or is_page. I combined it with the yoast filter to make this:

```php
<?php

add_filter('wpseo_robots', 'yoast_seo_robots_noindex');

// robots is a string 
// - eg. "index, follow, max-image-preview:large, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1"

function yoast_seo_robots_noindex($robots)
{
    // dev mode subdomains - to enforce no indexing on dev/staging environments
    $dev_subdomains = [
        'dev',
        'staging',
    ];

    // is the home_url starting with dev or staging?
    $is_dev = in_array(explode('.', parse_url(home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST))[0], $dev_subdomains);

    $noindex = 'noindex, follow';
    $is_no_index = is_noindexfollow(); //  existing noindex logic I had

    if ($is_no_index) {
        return $noindex;
    } else {
        return $is_dev ? $noindex : $robots;
    }
}

function is_noindexfollow()
{
    // Particular Query Data
    $noindex_params = [
        'PageSpeed',
        'pagespeed',
    ];

    if (!empty(array_intersect(array_keys($_GET), $noindex_params))) {
        return true;
    }

    // Regex Pattern match on URI
    $noindex_regexes = [
        //   '/your-path/(option1|option2)/*',
        //   '/oauth/*'
    ];

    $regex = '#' . implode('|', $noindex_regexes) . '#';

    if (!empty($noindex_regexes) && preg_match($regex, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return true;
    }

    $noindex_pages = []; // PAGES - use slug names
    $noindex_singles = []; // POSTS - can be ids or slugs

    // If we don't need to check for these, then skip this check.
    if (empty($noindex_pages) && empty($noindex_singles)) {
        return false;
    }

    $isNoIndexPage = !empty($noindex_pages) && is_page($noindex_pages);
    $isNoIndexSingle = !empty($noindex_singles) && is_single($noindex_singles);

    return $isNoIndexPage || $isNoIndexSingle;
}
```